# Exception Handling in MVVMLight

Tags: wpf, mvvm, view, mvvm-light

We are using MVVMLight with WPF. Our Views & ViewModels reside in different projects. All the unhandled exceptions occurring in Views can be handled by app.xaml.cs file but we would also like to catch the unhandled exceptions from ViewModel by providing some centralized exception handling mechanism instead of writing try..catch in every function. Please suggest something as to how we can achieve the above. 
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unhandled exceptions from ViewModels can also be handled in App.xaml.cs. There should not be much difference. App.xaml.cs is a central point of your entire application where you handle all the unhandled exceptions.

Side node: I would not recommend you splitting ViewModels and Views into different assemblies for this and other reasons. See my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166701/splitting-apps-parts-in-their-own-assemblies-when-using-prism/5167036#5167036) describing why.

Comment: Thanks, Pavlo, for your comments. For some reasons we have divided our application into different projects e.g. Views & ViewModels. I am not sure how to handle the exceptions raised in ViewModels project from app.xaml.cs which is lying in another project i.e. Views. Can you please point to some approaches?

Comment: @Anil - All exceptions that occur in your ViewModel classes will eventually come to your exception handler in App.xaml.cs (you need to regester DispatcherUnhandledException handler and AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException handler).

Comment: @Anil - If my post answers your question please mark it as answer by clicking the checkbox on the left of the post. If it was useful, you might also upvote it.